# Patterns in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a set of string and I am trying to use matches. 
My set of string, named patterns now has `[title@*, text@*, specification*/specificationText]` and I need to be able to convert it to `[title@(.*), text@(.*), specification(.*)/specificationText]` so that something like `specification1/specificationText` or anything else in place of 1 gets matched.

My string: `String abc = "specification1/specificationText";`

Can someone please help me with how to go about doing this?

The code that I have written,

```
private static Boolean isMatch(String abc, Set<String> patterns) {

    for (String pattern : patterns) {

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        if (r.matcher(abc).matches()) {

            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }

    return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

Right now `r` takes the value, `specification*/specification` which is being compared with `specification1/specification`. So `FALSE` is being returned.

Comment: Give better examples of what things you expect to match. More than one example. Also, what is wrong with the code you have currently written? What does it do? Where are you stuck? More info please.

Comment: Correction: I need to convert my set of string to, [title@(.*), text@(.*), specification(.*)/specification]. Right now r takes the value, specification*/specification which is being compared with specification1/specification. So FALSE is being returned

Comment: Quick fix: `Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern.replace("*", "(.*)"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to replace `*` with `(.*)`, just do it with `.replace("*", "(.*)")`:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern.replace("*", "(.*)"));
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/PaBC4u):

```
Set<String> patterns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("title@*", "text@*", "specification*/specificationText"));
String abc = "specification1/specificationText";
System.out.println(isMatch(abc, patterns));
// => true
```

And the method:

```
private static Boolean isMatch(String abc, Set<String> patterns) {
    for (String pattern : patterns) {
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern.replace("*", "(.*)"));
        if (r.matcher(abc).matches()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or even (to make it shorter, as you are not re-using the compiled regex):

```
private static Boolean isMatch(String abc, Set<String> patterns) {
    for (String pattern : patterns) {
        if (abc.matches(pattern.replace("*", "(.*)"))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Wiktor Stribiżew :)